# Macro not working as expected in Notepad++

Tags: macros, notepad++

I just installed notepad++ and i am having some problems with macros in it.

i have a simple text file below:

```
hi 
i am here
this is the third line
```

i kept the cursor at the first line before "hi".Now i selected start recording macro in the menu.i typed 'hi' before 'hi'(the actual word in the line) like below and pressed [Home] key in the keyboard and then pressed down arrow.Now i selected stop recording macro from the menu

```
hihi
i am here 
this is the third line
```

but when i run the macro i am getting the following output

```
hihi 
hˆi«i am here
hˆi«this is the third line
```

Could anybody please tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Odd; it works fine for me. Maybe something screwy with character encoding, or something? What character encoding is the file you're editing? Mine was the default, ANSI...

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm getting a similar thing. Strange characters when playing back a macro (same [Home] and down arrow), except `DC1` appears as the odd character?! Normal text, ANSI encoding, Notepad++ V5.7

Comment: @w3d.I could Not resolve.I have downloaded a new full version which is working fine.http://hotfile.com/dl/75486806/04a3046/Notepad_5.8.2_by_doctor.zip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same here as for Matt.  For language, I was in normal text.

Comment: Vijay, it's easier to clarify if you say which part you don't understand.  In the menu bar, choose Language and then Normal Text.  I think this may help you, because when I did a new test I got some funny results similar to yours, and then when I chose Normal Text and tried it again, it worked fine again.  Did I clarify the right part?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to, at least, version 5.8.2 where that problem was fixed. I was experiencing the same problem, upgraded to version 5.8.5 and the problem is gone.

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/release/5.8.2

```
Fix macro recording bug for the non-ASCII characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment at top, I have also been experiencing this same issue. Strange characters inserted when playing back a macro. This worked OK with previous versions, but appears to have been a bug introduced with version 5.7

It does appear to be an encoding issue. I have been able to workaround this issue by switching to UTF-8 encoding whilst recording the macro - as mentioned in the [comment of this bug report](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3074546&group_id=95717&atid=612382).

This has been [reported as a bug several times recently](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?limit=25&func=&group_id=95717&atid=612382&assignee=&status=&category=&artgroup=&keyword=&submitter=&artifact_id=&assignee=&status=&category=&artgroup=&submitter=&keyword=macro&artifact_id=&submit=Filter). Many are still *open*, however, [one is reported as *fixed*](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3074546&group_id=95717&atid=612382). And is [reported as fixed in the current release (5.8.2)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331754/topic/3905975) - which also introduces several new features as regards macros. However, nothing later than v5.7 is yet available from the auto-updater within Notepad++ itself. However, you can manually [download the latest installer from SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/).

Answer (score 1):

I turned off the auto complete feature and this fixed the issue for me.

[How do I stop Notepad++ from showing autocomplete for all words in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263705/how-do-i-stop-notepad-from-showing-autocomplete-for-all-words-in-the-file)

Comment: If you added a short statement on how to actually turn the feature off your answer would be even better ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem, I typed in some code and it came out wrong in macro.

Then I neglected the advice to type the code and not paste it, and so I copy/pasted the code I needed and it worked fine.

So my advice: write it somewhere else and copy/paste when you start macro.