# How do I stop Notepad++ from showing autocomplete for all words in the file

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++

I'm trying to use Notepad++ with the Progress programming language.

I have installed the language definition in `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Notepad++` as `userDefineLang.xml` and syntax highlighting is working correctly.

I've put a file in the `notepad++ Plugins\APIs` directory named `progress.xml`, but the contents are not recognized by Notepad++.

I've also removed all the other language files from that directory and Notepad++ still shows the exact same autocomplete suggestions it did before I removed them.

Also, when typing in a program, it looks like every word in the file is an auto-complete suggestion, not just the keywords or function names.

Anyone know how to track this down?

Answer (score 329):

Notepad++ provides 2 types of features:

- Auto-completion that read the open file and provide suggestion of words and/or functions within the file
- Suggestion with the arguments of functions (specific to the language)

Based on what you write, it seems what you want is auto-completion on function only + suggestion on arguments.

To do that, you just need to change a setting.

1. Go to `Settings` > `Preferences...` > `Auto-completion`
2. Check `Enable Auto-completion on each input`
3. Select `Function completion` and not `Word completion`
4. Check `Function parameter hint on input` (if you have this option)

On version 6.5.5 of Notepad++, I have this setting
[image: settings]

Some documentation about auto-completion is available in [Notepad++ Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Auto_Completion).

Comment: Is it possible to disable this only for normal text files?

Comment: @Mark Neu Not that I know. If you need this, you could try some other editors like Visual Code.

Comment: For the english version: `Alt+t>p>a>` and then a manual click on `"Enable auto-completion on each input"`. I have not yet applied https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609009/notepad-adding-a-new-shortcut-for-an-existing-command to map the last manual click to a keyboard command.

Comment: I like this feature, it would be nice to have an option to only do this on certain file extensions.  When you create a new file and have yet to save, it still does auto-completion, which I would like that disabled.

I've also noticed on an entirely blank file, starting to type the first word, the auto-completion box briefly comes up and goes away.  It's trying to auto-complete on the very first word.  It slows down typing.

Hoping this feature can get optimized a bit.

Comment: This works for the current session on Ubuntu. On each reboot this resets. Any idea? @Jean-FrancoisT.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan Is it Ubuntu run on a Thumbdrive? Are you admin user? No idea how to help you. Probably a question on https://askubuntu.com/  ??

Comment: Yeah running Ubuntu on my local machine as an admin

Answer (score 20):

The answer is to **DISABLE** "Enable auto-completion on each input". Tested and works perfectly.