# Notepad++: Adding a new shortcut for an existing command

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to make "Ctrl+G" to open the find dialogue, just as Ctrl+F" (so both shortcuts open the same "find dialogue").

I know I can modify the existing shortcuts of commands through "macro > modify shortcut", but it allows changing the shortcut only, not the "Name" of the command (shaded).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can add a second keybinding to the find dialog. Notepad++ does not offers this out of the box. We can only assign one keybinding.
We need a way to add a *second find dialog*. One way I can think of is by the very useful npp_exec plugin. It offers to create small automation-scripts and we can add these scripts to the menu. It also offers a (little hidden) way for assigning shortcuts for these scripts.

So the strategy is:

1. install npp_exec, you find it in the plugin manager and restart notepad++
2. create a npp_exec script with this content: `NPP_SENDMSG WM_COMMAND IDM_SEARCH_FIND`, save it, e.g. as **OpenFindDlg**, you create such a script by Plugins -> NppExec -> Execute..., enter the script and click Save...
3. Go to Plugins -> NppExec -> Advanced Options ...

   1. Select **OpenFindDlg** under Associated script
   2. give it a menu entry under Item name: e.g, *OpenFindDlg*
   3. Click Add/Modify, you want to get a new entry in the list area on the left, see screenshot: [image: NppExec Advanced Options filled]
4. restart Notepad++, so get this setting activated.
5. add the additional shortcut: goto Settings -> Shortcut mapper: somewhere under the Plugins tab, you will find the Name that you have saved the script, here **OpenFindDlg**. Now you can assign your shortcut `CTRL-G`.
   Take care that you have also deleted the existing keybinding `CTRL-G` for the goto line command somewhere under the Main menu Tab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But I don't want Ctrl+G only to open the find dialogue, I want also the Ctrl+F to find it as usual..  so if I click Ctrl+G or Ctrl+F both open the Find dialogue

Comment: OK, I see. You could try to record a macro for openning the find dialog, save it under a name and bind `CTRL-G` to that macro. Thus you have created a second object (the macro) for find and you have a second object where you can assign a shortcut to.

Comment: it doesn't record macro when I hit Ctrl+F

Comment: You are right, macro only works, when the dialog is filled with something and the find button is executed. Sorry.

Comment: Replaced my macro answer with a new answer, describing how to use npp_exec plugin to get a second entry for the find dialog, thus a second option for assigning a keyboard shortcut.