# Highlight and open local file path using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can I make notepad++ highlight a local file path found a file (like a hyperlink) and open the file in a new tab when clicked on?

At the moment I am using [this trick](http://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=NotepadPlusPlus_File_Navigation) which works but is cumbersome.

Edited;
To illustrate what I mean, say you have a log file (below) that contains a file path. It would be very nice to be able to click on that file path and open the file in another tab. Obviosuly I can copy the path and paste into open-file-dialog but that is tedious.

```
Starting application...

Reading file c:\temp\conf.ini
```

Setting "clickable link settings" to enabled (Preferences \ MISC) will make the path into a link if prefixed with file:///. However this does not appear to allow me to open the file in a tab. It also would require changes to our software which is not ideal.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Have you looked at the Notepad++ help pages? Are you asking for a new feature to be added to Notepad++? If so then is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: Supplied more information in original post. Have obviously looked at docs and googled. Notepad++ is a tool with many options and plugins. I honestly do not know if this is a new feature, a plugin or some simple configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the NppExec plugin (you can install it from PluginMangager) available, you can use this script.

```
NPP_OPEN $(CURRENT_WORD)
```

Then:

1. mark the filepath in the file so that is is hightlighted,
2. Use Plugins -> NppExec -> Execute ... (you can assign a keyboard shortcut for this command)
3. Select the script (you have to paste and save it under some name the first time)

If everything works right, you can assign a keyboard shortcut of its own to the script, see [here for the details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611800/4086774) . Then it would be : select the path and use the keyboard shortcut.